# Avoiding tables (HTML) to show business information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, user-experience

I want to learn new techniques to show business information to my user.

I'm working in a management system that is a web aplication and it's been writen using MVC Razor .NET, Entity Framework and Angular JS.

In a particular page my client wants to see a bunch of information and he's used to use excel, so he asked me to make a table to keep the excel similarity. BUT here is the point I want to improve him experience.

I dont want to use tables, because it is a lot of information (at least 15 columns), I know that I can have some column selector so the user can choice what columns he wants to see and that kind of stuff but the problem is that is very import to him see all informations right away.

I wonder what kind of UX techniques, methods or frameworks I can use to give him a better experience.

Thank you.

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for.  Can you give more context?  You don't want tables but you want to show all the data in a table?

Comment: Actually I need other ways or techniques to show this information avoiding tables.

Like, how to show the information that is in a table with 15 columns and N rows, using I do not know divs, boxes, panels, etc.

What I want is to know if there is any UX technique or method to dealing if this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what tables are meant for.  If you are looking to make it clean and easy to manage I would use bootstrap and maybe a jquery plugin like the following:

Bootstrap Example

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

http://www.datatables.net/